# How do I make or loop with if statement to change color from green to orange and back again?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me with my code bellow? Can't seem to figure out how to loop through all the elements in array to change their background color from green to orange and back again on click. What I want it to do is change the background color of each specific div to orange on click and back to green again..and so on. What am I doing wrong?

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Working With JavaScript Functions</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='testA' style="background-color: green;" class="box"></div>
    <div id='testB' style="background-color: green;"  class="box"></div>
    <div id='testC' style="background-color: green;"  class="box"></div>
    <div id='testD' style="background-color: green;"  class="box"></div>
    <div id='testE' style="background-color: green;"  class="box"></div>
    <div id='testF' style="background-color: green;"  class="box"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
.box {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

//javascript

```
let greenBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

function boxClicked(event) {
    
  for (let i = 0; i <=greenBox.length; i++){

    if (greenBox[i].style.backgroundColor === 'green') {
      greenBox[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

    } else {
      greenBox[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
  }
}

greenBox.addEventListener('click', boxClicked);
```

Comment: Take a look at what `getElementsByClassName()` returns - `greenBox` will be a collection you'll need to loop over to add the event listeners.

Comment: How do I do that?
What is wrong with my js code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are trying to add an event listener to a `HTMLCollection` interface, which is invalid.

If what you want to do is to allow each `.box` div's background-colour to be changed on-click **individually**, you can setup a loop on page-load to add the event listener to each `.box` div, then use the `srcElement` property of the `event` object to change the background colour.

Also, a minor suggestion unrelated to the question, consider renaming `greenBox` to something more accurate like `boxes` as the variable holds a collection of elements and they will not always be green. This is implemented in the solution below:

```
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

for (let box of boxes) {
  box.addEventListener('click', boxClicked);
}

function boxClicked(event) {
  event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor =
    event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor === 'green' ? 'orange' : 'green';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Damon, Thank you. Your code seems to be working. can I ask you, what is the purpose of "event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = " being blank?

Comment: No worries, and its simply just the way my formatter in vs code has dealt with the long single line. The next line continues that statement until the `;`. So the full statement is `event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor === 'green' ? 'orange' : 'green';`

Comment: Oh.. alright. Thank you for swift reply. My question then is why is first bit needed ( event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = ) ?

Comment: The first is the assignment (`=`) of the `backgroundColor` property, and the second uses a strict equality operator (`===`) to check what the background colour already is and returns the correct colour string (using a ternary operator) to the assignment.

Comment: Brilliant explanation Damon. Makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code. You need to have event listener inside a loop to perform for each HTML element. In your code it is a collection of HTML Elements that hasn't a event listening property.

```
let greenBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

for (const g of greenBox) {
   g.addEventListener('click', boxClicked);
}

function boxClicked(event) {
     event.target.style.backgroundColor = event.target.style.backgroundColor === 'green' ? 'orange' : 'green';
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhavya, Thank you for the answer. Your code worked in a way. I needed it to turn boxes orange on the individual basis. Your's turned them all orange at once. Probably didn't explain it right. Thank you for the answer anyway!

Comment: Then I will edit my answer. Have a look

Comment: This is now working. Can you please explain to me why is "event.target.style.backgroundColor = " needed?

Comment: That event references the event for current element for which event listener is attached. event.target references the curent element for which action is performed. event.target.backgroundColor is needed so that we can change color only on the curent element which is clicked

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on the last line in the js script when you call `assEventListener` on `greenBox` which is an array.

Instead of doing that you can add the `onClick` property to each div so:

```
<div id='testA' style="background-color: green;" class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
<div id='testB' style="background-color: green;"  class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
<div id='testC' style="background-color: green;"  class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
<div id='testD' style="background-color: green;"  class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
<div id='testE' style="background-color: green;"  class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
<div id='testF' style="background-color: green;"  class="box" onClick="boxClicked()"></div>
```